# Converting characters to dates in R

Tags: r, date, character, as.date

```r
df = data.frame(date = c("Jan-22", "Feb-22", "Mar-23"))
```

where `"Jan-22"` means January 2022, etc.

`class(df$date)` returns that the values are characters rather than dates. I have tried the following to change to `Date`:

```r
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

issues

> Error in charToDate(x) :
> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> and

```r
library(dplyr)
df$date <- df$date %>% as.character() % as.Date()
```

does not work either.

How can I convert this column of characters to `Date`s?

Comment: If you are attempting to create an object of class `Date`, pad with a year first, then convert, i.e. `as.Date(paste0("2024-", c("Jan-22", "Feb-22", "Mar-23")), "%Y-%b-%d")`

Comment: Applied to your variable names:  `df$date = as.Date(paste0("2024-", df$date), "%Y-%b-%d")`

Comment: Ah sorry I think I wasn't clear in my question (edited now) - Jan-22 means January 2022, so my column contains data which runs to Jan-24 (i.e. 24 rows - one for each month).

Comment: Seems like you did not get the principle. Simply do `df$date = as.Date(paste0("01-", df$date), "%d-%b-%Y")` then.

Comment: Sorry I understood that to be read as a date, the year must be 4 figures long so I was trying to work out how to paste "20" after the dash. If that is not necessary then great - much simpler!

Comment: How about: `lubridate::my(df$date)`

Comment: @DaveArmstrong this looks right. But applying my next function: `df_SPC <- ptd_spc(df, value_field = count, date_field = date, facet_field = OrgCode, improvement_direction = "increase")` I get the following error `Error: date_field must be a Date or POSIXt vector ('date' is a 'yearmon')`

Comment: How about, `as.POSIXct(lubridate::my(df$date))`

Comment: This should work if you follow my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try `as.yearmon()` function from the `zoo` package:

```
> require(zoo)
> as.yearmon(df$date, format = "%b-%y")
[1] "Jan 2022" "Feb 2022" "Mar 2023"
```

Then you can coerce that to Date as such:

```
> as.Date.yearmon(as.yearmon(df$date, format = "%b-%y"))
[1] "2022-01-01" "2022-02-01" "2023-03-01"
```